# Output ${projSRC} to file in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, file

I am writing a Bash script that creates a CMakeLists.txt file for a project.
The problem arises at this portion:

```
    echo "file(GLOB projSRC src/*.cpp)" >> CMakeLists.txt
```

After that, I need the program to output `${SOURCES}` into CMakeLists.txt
I don't mean a variable in the script named SOURCES, I mean it should actually write the plaintext `${SOURCES}`.

What I mean is, the final file should look this like:

```
arbitrary_command(target PROJECT sources ${SOURCES})
```

and not like:

```
arbitrary_command(target PROJECT sources [insert however bash messes it up here])
```

**How can I do this in my Bash script?**

Comment: BTW, it's not good form to use `>> outputFile` over and over -- every time you put that on a command, the shell opens the output file for append before running that one line, and closes the output file again after. It's much more efficient to redirect stdout for a whole block: `{ echo "hello"; echo "world"; } >outputFile`

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes, not double quotes, for a literal string:

```
echo 'file(GLOB ${projSRC} src/*.cpp)' >> CMakeLists.txt
```

That said, you might consider using a heredoc (or even a quoted heredoc) in this case, to write the entire file as one command:

```
cat >CMakeLists.txt <<'EOF'
everything here will be emitted to the file exactly as written
${projSRC}, etc
even over multiple lines
EOF
```

...or, if you want *some* substitutions, an unquoted heredoc (that is, one where the sigil -- `EOF` in these examples -- isn't quoted at the start):

```
foo="this"
cat >CMakeLists.txt <<EOF
here, parameter expansions will be honored, like ${foo}
but can still be quoted: \${foo}
EOF
```

---

You can also have multiple commands writing output to a single redirection, to avoid paying the cost of opening your output file more than once:

```
foo=this
{
  echo "Here's a line, which is expanded due to double quotes: ${foo}"
  echo 'Here is another line, with no expansion due to single quotes: ${foo}'
} >CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

May be I don't understand your question...

But

```
echo \${SOURCES}
```

will print

```
${SOURCES}
```

for you.

Comment: It was THAT simple!?

Comment: The bare command works for that specific case, but good practice is still to use quotes -- without them you get glob expansions (unless quoted for), string-splitting changing whitespace to different kinds (ie. changing tabs to spaces, or changing several spaces into just one space, or deleting leading or trailing spaces), etc.

Comment: ...that's especially important for file formats like makefiles where whitespace types matter.

Comment: I'am partially agreed... the solution with single-quotes works as well and probably better for some situations.
For me, I thought at first about solution with escaping \ because sometimes I need to have at the same line some variables and some $not_a_variable texts.